# Selenium PHPUnit setup/teardown loop

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit

I'm trying to run Selenium 4.5 tests with PHPUnit 9.5.25 and ChromeDriver (Chrome v106.0.5249.61). Tests run successfully, but afterwards I seem to get into a setUp()/tearDown() loop, and PHPUnit never exits gracefully. I've pared the file down to only the setup() and tearDown() methods and am still seeing the same behavior:

```
<?php

class UATest extends PHPUnit\Extensions\Selenium2TestCase {

    protected function setUp(): void {
        var_dump('setup');
        $this->setHost('localhost');
        $this->setPort(4444);
        $this->setBrowser('chrome');
        $this->setBrowserUrl('***');
    }


    protected function tearDown(): void {
        var_dump('teardown');
        $this->stop();
    }


}
```

This is the output:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.25 #StandWithUkraine

R/***/UATest.php:13:
string(5) "setup"
/***/UATest.php:13:
string(5) "setup"
/***/UATest.php:22:
string(8) "teardown"
R/***/UATest.php:13:
string(5) "setup"
/***/UATest.php:22:
string(8) "teardown"
/***/UATest.php:22:
string(8) "teardown"
E/***/UATest.php:13:
string(5) "setup"
/***/UATest.php:22:
string(8) "teardown"
```

Does anybody know what might cause that?